# How to tell number of rows changed from JDBC execution

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm uncertain as to how to get the number of rows affected from a SQL execution.

I do like this:

```java
boolean isResultSet = statement.execute(arbitrarySQLCommand);
```

and I can get the number of rows affected from the `getUpdateCount()` method. That is all fine. The problem I have is when update count is zero. This can either mean:

1. It was a DML statement but it didn't affect any rows. Zero rows affected is a valid response. I just means that some condition was not met.
2. It was a non-DML statement (DDL statement most likely) .. which by definition does not change rows so therefore update count is always zero (duh!). Or to put it another way: The concept of *update count* is meaningless for such statements.

What I would like is to be able to **distinguish between situation 1 and 2 above**. How?

I'm not interested in statements that produce output so I could also use [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) but as I see it the return value from that method has the same flaw:

> Returns:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Arghhh!
I wish it was:

> Returns:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) -1 for SQL statements that return nothing

(note: I do not know the contents of `arbitrarySQLCommand` beforehand)

### Final chosen solution

There just doesn't seem to be a true JDBC-like solution to the problem. In my mind the designers of JDBC has made a serious mistake on the `getUpdateCount` by using the value 0 (zero) to signify a statement that doesn't (by definition) affect rows because zero rows affected is also a perfectly valid value for the outcome of a DML statement.

The only possible solution seems to be to do some kind of pattern matching on the SQL statement to figure out if it is a DML statement (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) or another type of SQL statement. Something like this:

1. Extract first word from `arbitrarySQLCommand`. A word is terminated
   by either a whitespace or a EOL line char.
2. If that word (ignoring
   case) is either INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE then it is a DML statement
   and the output from `getUpdateCount()` is relevant, otherwise the
   output from `getUpdateCount()` is irrelevant.

Ugly and error prone. But the only possible solution that came out of this SO question. :-(

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.webdbtips.com/205029/) ?

Comment: @The New Idiot: Thanks, but as I see it that blog just points to the same design problem in JDBC as I have run into.

Comment: Normally you would *know* whether your SQL statement was an update statement or not, so you would know whether to call executeQuery(), executeUpdate(), etc.

Comment: @EJP: If I'm creating a GUI application where the user can input an arbitrary SQL statement then I *don't* know the SQL statement in advance. It doesn't really matter if I use `executeQuery()`, `executeUpdate()`, etc, as they all suffer from the described problem.

Comment: No, they *don't* all 'suffer from the described problem' at all. executeUpdate() and executeBatch() both return *exactly what you are looking for.* I suggest you revise your design or else take the hint from the answer here and call a different method depending on the first word of the query. It's not difficult and thanks to the syntax of SQL it's not in the least ambiguous.

Comment: @EJP:  Let us review: As an example (that you say will fit the requirement) lets look at the returned value from `executeUpdate()`: *either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing*. The problem is that 0 (zero) is also a possible return value from a DML statement so I cannot from the return value distinguish between DML statements and non-DML statements.

Comment: You're just repeating yourself. I know what they return. My point is that normally you know what you've executed so you know what the return value means. The problem could only arise if you are building a library for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best you can do is checking the SQL statement

```
Set<String> dmlCommands = new HashSet<String>() {
  {
    add("UPDATE"); add("INSERT"); add("DELETE"); //Add more DML commands ....
  }
};
int updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();
for(String dml : dmlCommands) {
    if(arbitrarySQLCommand.toUpperCase().contains(dml) && updateCount == 0) {
        updateCount = -1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a full proof solution. I can have column name as insert or update

Comment: You might want to do `startsWith()` rather than `contains()` to make it a little bit more safe. However it still doesn't feel like the right way to solve the problem to me.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer - reluctantly. The reason why I'm reluctant is that I really don't like the solution but it seems to be the *only* solution and for this you should of course be credited. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe my answer does not help you with what you asked exactly, but I got here when I searched how to get the **affected** row count after running a DML, not **found** row count - with MySQL. And I write here what I found to help others.

My problem was that when I run a statement that does not do any change in the table, for example

```
UPDATE table SET field=1 WHERE field=1
```

method `Statement.executeUpdate(...)` returned the number of found rows, not the number of changed/affected rows. So I couldn't tell if the query modified something in the table.

To change this, an option should be provided in the url when the connection is created ( with`DriverManager.getConnection()`), like this:

`jdbc:mysql://${jdbc.host}/${jdbc.db}?`**`useAffectedRows=true`**

I found it here:

http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Return-number-of-changed-rows-tp3888464p3903155.html

And MySQL documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html