# joining multiple tables to fetch records and fetch count

Tags: mysql, database

I Need a help to fetch record count and I have 3 tables as mentioned below and joining these tables based on Transaction_Id and that transaction id's pulled from Header based on file creation date
Below are the sample data.

```
Table Names and columns and data

Entry - ID,Transaction_ID,Dfi_Acct_Nbr,Individual_Name
ID, Transaction_ID, Dfi_Acct_Nbr,   Individual_Name
'1'    '108'    'test_Dfi_Acct_Nbr' 'test_Name'
'2'    '110'    '23456789'         'Test Name'
'3'    '113'    '099898'             'RK'

Addenda - ID,Transaction_ID,Return_Description
ID, Transaction_ID, Return_Description
'9'    '113'.           'T Desc'
'10'    '108'           'test_Description'
'11'    '110'           '041152667'

Batch - ID,Transaction_ID,Standard_Code
 ID, Transaction_ID, Standard_Code
 '5'    '108'            ''
 '6'    '110'           'WEB'

Header - ID,Transaction_ID,File_Creation_Date 
ID, Transaction_ID, File_Creation_Date
'15'   '115'            '220315'
'16'   '110'            '220513'
'18'   '113'            '220315'
'19'   '108'            '220514'
```

Below is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(e.Transaction_ID) as TotalCount, 
   e.Dfi_Acct_Nbr,e.Individual_Name,a.Return_Description,h.Standard_Code      
FROM ENTRY e 
JOIN ADDENDA a ON e.Transaction_ID = a.Transaction_ID
JOIN BATCH h ON h.ransaction_ID = a.Transaction_ID
WHERE e.Transaction_ID in (SELECT Transaction_Id 
  FROM HEADER WHERE File_Creation_Date BETWEEN '220512' AND '220514') 
GROUP BY  e.Dfi_Acct_Nbr,e.Individual_Name, a.Return_Description,  h.Standard_Code
```

I am getting the output as below

```
  TotalCount, Dfi_Acct_Nbr,    Individual_Name, Return_Description,  Standard__Code
 '1',       'test_Dfi_Acct_Nbr','test_Name',  'test_Description',    ''
 '1',       '23456789','        'Test Name',   '041152667',          'WEB'
```

Since my query pulls 2 recods it should display TotalCount as 2

```
TotalCount, Dfi_Acct_Nbr,    Individual_Name, Return_Description,  Standard__Code
 '2',       'test_Dfi_Acct_Nbr','test_Name',  'test_Description',    ''
 '2',       '23456789',        'Test Name','   '041152667',          'WEB'
```

Answer (score 0):

the SQL uses `group by` like :

> GROUP BY  e.Dfi_Acct_Nbr,e.Individual_Name, a.Return_Description,  h.Standard_Code

the `COUNT(e.Transaction_ID) as TotalCount` is counted inside each group, instead of the total rows returned.

Comment: then how to return total rows to my output ?

Comment: this depends on the language you are using, there should be an `affectedRows` attribute for a sql execution results.  and for a `select` sql， just check the lenghs of the result array.

Comment: here's a reference:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544782/how-to-tell-number-of-rows-changed-from-jdbc-execution.